# Protractor - When i start the "webdriver-manager start" error Failed to start: SocketListener0@0.0.0.0:4444 displayed

Tags: automation, protractor, angularjs-e2e

when i start the webdriver-manager below error displayed kindly help on this.

> seleniumProcess.pid: 8248 18:04:32.009 INFO - Launching a standalone
>   Selenium Server Setting system property webdriver.chrome.driver to
>   C:\Users\lokesh.m\AppData\Roa
>   ming\npm\node_modules\protractor\selenium\chromedriver.exe
>   18:04:32.602 INFO - Java: Oracle Corporation 25.71-b15 18:04:32.602
>   INFO - OS: Windows 7 6.1 amd64 18:04:32.742 INFO - v2.47.1, with Core
>   v2.47.1. Built from revision 411b314 18:04:33.085 INFO - Driver class
>   not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver 18:04:33.085 INFO -
>   Driver provider com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver is not re gistered
>   18:04:33.881 WARN - Failed to start: SocketListener0@0.0.0.0:4444
>   Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Selenium is already
>   running o n port 4444. Or some other service is.
>           at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer.start(SeleniumServer.java:4
>   92)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer.boot(SeleniumServer.java:30
>   5)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer.main(SeleniumServer.java:24
>   5)
>           at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher.main(GridLauncher.java:64)
>   Selenium Standalone has exited with code 1

I tried by updating the JAVA as it was advised in some issues but it is not working.

Comment: also tried to shutdown the selenium server by giving this URL. http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/driver/?cmd=shutDownSeleniumServer - but this is not working

Comment: to my surprise when i started the selenium server today. it was working fine. May be due to system shutdown the process could have closed i guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your server is already running based on the error `Selenium is already running o n port 4444`. Find the pid of the java process (with ps aux for instance) and kill it. Then try restarting

Comment: yea i knew this. i tried to shutdown the server through URL but i cant do it. any other way to find the java process and kill it.

Comment: Shutdown via url may not be working. If you are windows, open task manager and kill or try [this](http://tweaks.com/windows/39559/kill-processes-from-command-prompt/?sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi745aGt93KAhUD7WMKHRdlDP8Q9QEIDjAA)

Comment: to my surprise when i started the selenium server today. it was working fine. May be due to system shutdown the process could have closed i guess.